# iPhone "un-downloading" photos in Messages

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, messages

For any messages with pictures in my phone that are older than about 1 day, my iPhone seems to "un-download" the picture when I'm viewing the message in Messages and gives me an option to `Tap To Download` for an image that I already downloaded yesterday. After another day passes it'll once again be "un-downloaded" (sorry I don't have a better term for it).

This is rather annoying to constantly have to redownload the same photos.

How do I stop my phone from "un-downloading" the message's picture attachments?

I'm on an iPhone 8 running iOs 14.5.1. (And yes, I know I could save the image to my phone, but that also seems unnecessary.)

Comment: How much free space do you have, and is the iMessage enabled in iCloud settings?

Comment: Yes, iMessage is enabled in iCloud, and it does seem like I'm close to my max storage (62 of 64 GB used). Are the photos likely deleting automatically because of that?

Comment: Yup - if you turn off iMessage in the iCloud settings it'll stop auto-deleting but you'll also run out of space and not sure what it'll do to resolve those two inherently at-odds issues.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well at least I know *why* they're deleting now and can make some choices about it. If you want to convert your comment to an answer I'll accept it as the right one! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have iMessage iCloud Syncing enabled (this switch is located in iCloud settings, as opposed to iMessage settings, your device will remove downloads since they're stored in your iCloud account. This is done to keep your local storage space available.

If you turn off this feature, your phone will probably download your messages. However, if you don't have enough space I do not know what solution it will propose.

In theory, if you have sufficient space, iMessage iCloud Syncing will not remove your local file downloads.